# Mocked Http get service request for angular unit test fails because of typing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typeerror

once more I'm trying to write a test for a http get request and it fails because of datatyping (at least that's what I suspect).

The request I want to test works and looks like that

```
  getTypeFilter(): Observable<Typefilter[]> {
    const url = this.endpoint.getEndpoint() + 'testdata/types?language=' + this.language;
    return new Observable<Typefilter[]>(observer => {
      this.httpc.get<any[]>(url).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          const resultData: Typefilter[] = [];
          for (const item of data) {
            resultData.push(new Typefilter(item.id, item.name));
          }
          observer.next(resultData);
          observer.complete();
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

excerpts from my test file look like this

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { UrlService } from 'src/app/_services/url.service';
import { Typefilter } from '../_classes/typefilter';

describe('DataService', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let service: DataService;
  let urlService: UrlService;
  let mockType: Typefilter;

  mockType = {id: 1, name: 'News'};

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
    urlService = TestBed.inject(UrlService);
    urlService.getEndpoint = () => ('http://someaddress/');
  });

  it('getTypeFilter - should return TypeFilter', () => {
    service.getTypeFilter().subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual([mockType]);
    });
    const reqMock = httpMock.expectOne((req) => req.method === 'GET' && req.url === urlService.getEndpoint() + 'testdata/types?language=' + 'de');
    expect(reqMock.request.method).toBe('GET');
    reqMock.flush(mockType);
  });
});
```

But it fails with
**'TypeError: msgtypefilterkriterium is not iterable'** - which I do understand since the data I'm recieving in my request is an array of objects and my mocked Data is only an object. But when I mock this data as an array I do get the error: **'Expected $[0] to be a kind of Object, but was Typefilter({ id: 1, name: 'News' }).'**
Can anyone help me out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mockType` is an object, whereas `getTypeFilter` iterates the response `for (const item of data)`.
Therefore `reqMock.flush` should use an array too.

Try `reqMock.flush([mockType]);`

about types issues, it could be fixed like that:

```js
service.getTypeFilter().subscribe((data) => {
  expect(data).toEqual([new Typefilter(mockType.id, mockType.name)]);
});
```

Comment: I thought so too, but as already described, if I change the information I get the second error: Expected $[0] to be a kind of Object, but was Typefilter({ id: 1, name: 'News' })

Comment: right, that's expected, because prototypes are compared. Therefore `expect` should be adjusted, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was on the right track, but couldn't solve it correctly yet. THANK YOU SO MUCH!